# How to implement search bar in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to implement a tab bar application in which a tab is provided with Search bar.
When I click on the Search button after entering some data into the search field, I should get a `tableview` displaying the search results. The `tableview` should be added as a subview.
How should I implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UISearchBar is a control in toolbox, you need to implement it, and implement search button press event to add tableview as a subview.

you can consult with the similar thread here

[UISearchBar Sample Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302962/uisearchbar-sample-code)

Answer (score 3):

You need to take a look at Apple's [UISearchDisplayController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class reference documentation - this covers precisely what you're attempting to do and contains a link to a sample project (see the "Related sample code" section at the top) if you require some example code to look at.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://ved-dimensions.blogspot.com/2009/02/iphone-development-adding-search-bar-in.html

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create two different tables

1. One for showing all values.
2. Second For showing searched result.

and implement these two delegates of `UISearchBarDelegate,UISearchDisplayDelegate`

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
```