# how to add textfield and button programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, programmatically-created

I have a tableView and I want to apply search facility on tableView. For that I require textField and search Button but I don't know how to create these programmatically. so plz tell me how to create these two tools.

thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following link which describes for asynchronous scrollbar example

http://blog.patrickcrosby.com/2010/04/27/iphone-ipad-uisearchbar-uisearchdisplaycontroller-asynchronous-example.html

But you can also refer the previous post 
[UISearchBar Sample Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302962/uisearchbar-sample-code)

For more methods of implementing and getting results as you type, go to apples document and refer [UISearchBarDelegate Protocol Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UISearchBarDelegate)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the documentation for [UITextField](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html) and [UIButton](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html). You might also find [UISearchBar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) useful, which incorporates both a text field and a button.

Add your views to the table view's header view.

Answer (score 0):

You have a table delegate `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath`. In this delegate add the following code.

```
//Suppose you want to add textfield and button at the first row
if(indexPath.Row == 0)
{
         UITextField *txtSearch = [UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,150,35)];
         UIButton *btnSearch = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtoTypeCustom];
         btnSearch.frame = CGRectMake(160,0,50,35);

         [[cell contentView] addSubView:txtSearch];
         [[cell contentView] addSubView:btnSearch];
}
```

Also You can add event for button like

```
[btnSearch addTarget:self action:@selector(eventName) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Thanks