# Xcode add search to root view in splitviewcontroller

Tags: xcode, xcode4, ios5, uisplitviewcontroller, uisearchbar

I have a nib structure as shown in this image:

[image: nib]

Is there a way to add a Search bar in the Root VC? When I try to drag one in, it doesn't seem to like it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add a tableView to the Root View Controller before you can add the search bar.

Comment: I am actually adding the table view programmatically. Sorry for the red herring.. I guess I need to find a way to add the search bar programmatically too. Ideas welcome.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302962/uisearchbar-sample-code

Comment: Thanks again Andrew. I will mark this as answered as you did answer my original question. On the links you gave me - they are quite old (ios3). Has anything major changed?

Comment: Things may have changed if you are using things like story boards but I still use the same search bar techniques that I used in iOS 3